# Pentaho Data Integration - How to loop csv file column and each column will create a table

Tags: csv, pentaho, kettle

I am new in Pentaho Data Integration. I need help/guide on how to loop the csv file column and each column will create a table on it.

I was able to Generate the CSV file via Text File Input and CSV Input step. My problem is I don't know what step to loop through CSV column. I tried to search on the internet but I didn't find similar problem.

`Example:
Account,Contact,Location
Acct-01,"Name 1", "Location 1"
Acct-02,"Name 2", "Location 2"
Acct-03,"Name 3", "Location 3"
Acct-04,"Name 4", "Location 4"`

The output should create 3 tables which are Account, Contact, and Location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you need to use *Header Row Present* in **CSV File Input** step. 
   Now, your first row contains all names you need.
2. To get first row only, you could use **Sample Rows** step to get it (just provide line number threr).
3. Now you somehow need to split row with three values into three rows. You could first use **Concat fields** step and then **Split fields to rows** step. Now, you have three rows with your table names.
4. The step **Execute SQL script** allows you to run custom SQL for every row, for example `create table ${column_name} (col1 varchar(10))`. Just don't forget to use *Execute for each row* and  *Variable substitution*.